# Managing ZFS scrub via systemd

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, systemd, zfs

I would like to automate zpool scrubbing on my ZFS server. I have written the following systemd service as `/etc/systemd/system/zfs-scrub.service`)

```
[Unit]
Description=Scrub ZFS tank pool

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'zpool scrub `zpool list -H -o name`'
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c 'zpool scrub -s `zpool list -H -o name`'
```

As well as a timer (as `/etc/system.d/system/zfs-scrub.timer`) :

```
[Unit]
Description=Run zpool scrub every 1st Saturday

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sat *-*-* 22:00:00
```

After having started it a few weeks back, I checked to see if it behaved. It seems that systemd still thinks the service is running, so the timer didn't run.

It seems there is no `ExecStatus`, so systemd doesn't know that the service completed.

- Am I missing something ? Should I instead write a script that starts the scrub, greps the zpool status line and catch signals to stop the scrub when systemd signals it ?
- Is it possible to write a `OnCalendar` line that means "once per month, only on weekends" ?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question, the following can be read as running the first seven days of each month at a minute past midnight, but only if that day is also a Sunday.  Thus, it should run the first Sunday of every month.

```
OnCalendar=Sun *-*-01..07 00:01:00
```

Regarding your first question, it would be helpful to see what the journal says, rather than just confirming it ran via the zpool status command.  I notice that your service unit does not require the zfs.target.  Also I would make the service Type a "oneshot" rather than "simple".

EDIT:  This should work for you, though you need to start/enable for each pool:

Try this for your zfs-scrub@.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Scrub ZFS tank pool

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/zpool scrub %i
```

Then this for your zfs-scrub@.timer file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run zpool scrub every 1st Saturday

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sun *-*-01..07 00:01:00
```

You would then start the service via the timer with:

```
systemctl start zfs-scrub@[pool name].timer
systemctl enable zfs-scrub@[pool name].timer
```

Comment: I chose `simple` over `oneshot` because zpool scrub won't stay around (it just triggers the scrubbing and exits). The thing is that there's no text reporting when you trigger scrub (maybe exit codes, but I haven't checked), apart from grepping zpool status from time to time to get status/progress, and I didn't want to write a wrapper.

Comment: I see what you mean.  For what it's worth, what I've shown above is pretty much what I use on both my server and primary workstation (although I modified the timer to fit your requirements).  I've had no problems, although I don't know how to get the progress of a scrub other than via `zpool status`.

Comment: OpenZFS 2.0 introduced a parameter `-w` to make `zpool scrub` run in the foreground.